# Pandas - Create a column (col D) with values from (col C) if value in column (col A) is observed in (col B)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe A with 2524 rows with columns as shown.
To put in context, it is a genomic study where status 1 or 2 mean control or sick, respectively. The status value is related to the column id, e.g sample_1 (index 0) is sick, sample 5 (index 4) is a control.

```
          fid          iid       father       mother  sex  status
0        fam_7     sample_1            0            0    1       2
1     sample_2     sample_2            0            0    2       2
2     sample_3     sample_3            0            0    1       2
3     sample_4     sample_4            0            0    2       1
4       fam_34     sample_5            0            0    1       1
```

...        ...          ...          ...          ...  ...     ...
2519    fam_96  sample_2520            0  sample_1132    1       1
2520    fam_97  sample_2521   sample_760            0    1       2
2521    fam_98  sample_2522  sample_1452            0    2       2
2522    fam_99  sample_2523  sample_1793            0    1       2
2523   fam_100  sample_2524  sample_2002            0    1       2

Note that the column father and mother contain value 0. In this case, it mean that they don't have parent but rather are the parent.

I want to create 2 new columns ['Father status'] and ['mother status']. I want to find if the value in column 'father', and column 'mother', is in column id, and then had the status. As one can see, at index 2519 we can read sample_1132 in column (mother). I wish to add the status of that mother ['mother status'] in order to determine if a kid need both parent to be sick.

For better representation, I made a separated Dataframe only for the 'kids':

```
       fid          iid       father       mother     sex  status
2426   fam_3  sample_2427  sample_1015  sample_1776    1       1
2427   fam_4  sample_2428  sample_1263  sample_1985    2       1
2428   fam_5  sample_2429   sample_517  sample_1508    1       1
2429   fam_6  sample_2430  sample_1753   sample_490    2       1
2430   fam_7  sample_2431     sample_1   sample_312    2       1
2432   fam_9  sample_2433  sample_1845  sample_1627    1       1
2434  fam_11  sample_2435   sample_574  sample_1682    2       1
2435  fam_12  sample_2436   sample_275   sample_947    2       1

2424   fam_1  sample_2425  sample_2397  sample_2351    1       2
2425   fam_2  sample_2426  sample_2063   sample_818    2       2
2431   fam_8  sample_2432   sample_239  sample_1151    2       2
2433  fam_10  sample_2434   sample_171   sample_747    2       2
2440  fam_17  sample_2441  sample_2042  sample_1540    2       2
2441  fam_18  sample_2442  sample_2182   sample_252    2       2
2444  fam_21  sample_2445  sample_1730  sample_1190    2       2
2448  fam_25  sample_2449  sample_1315   sample_762    1       2
```

my expected output would be something like this

```
       fid          iid       father       mother     sex  status  f_st  m_st 
2434  fam_11  sample_2435   sample_574  sample_1682    2       1     1     2
2435  fam_12  sample_2436   sample_275   sample_947    2       1     1     1  
2424   fam_1  sample_2425  sample_2397  sample_2351    1       2     2     2
2425   fam_2  sample_2426  sample_2063   sample_818    2       2     2     1
```

Comment: please show ur expected output because the text is confusing, and post a part of the data that is representative to ur case, because all i see is that father and mother are 0s and ure telling us to compare it to id

Comment: does it make more sens like tis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose to obtain the column `mother status` with a merge:

```
# Get the "status" column of the mother thanks to her index in the "id" column  
df = df.merge(df[["id", "status"]], left_on="mother", right_on="id", how="left", suffixes=('', '_y'))
# Drop the duplicated id column coming from the merge
df.drop("id_y", axis=1, inplace=True)
# Rename the status columns with the desired name
df.rename(columns={"status_y": "mother_status"}, inplace=True)
```

I let you handle the NaN values in the `mother_status` column.